# How can I stop the bin liner falling in to the bin?

Tags: cleaning, plastics, trash

Often as I fill my bin, the bag sinks deeper and the edge of the bag ends up inside. Inevitably due to my laziness, rubbish then ends up inside the bin, but not inside the liner.

This makes me more reluctant to empty the bin as it's more of a chore and the problem worsens?

What can I do to stop the bin liner falling into the bin? I attempt to trap the bag with the lid but it's not enough.